# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects launch condition check not work for .net 4.7.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am using visual studio professional at version: This version announced as supported  .net framework 4.7.1

I installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects extension from the market.

Generate a visual studio setup project to generate MSI for a .net framework windows service console application, inside "Launch Condition" tag, set the .net framework version is target to 4.7.1.

The msi launch check works fine in any system below 4.7 like (4.6.1/4.6/4.5.2....) the launch check will prevent installer to be launched, but in OS system with windows 2012 R2 with .net 4.7 installed, the launch check should expected also as failed. But .net 4.7 pass the launch check and continually launch the installer.

Is anyone facing the same problem and is there a solution for this? I need to support launch check of .net 4.7.1 in my Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 installer project.

Comment: Why do you assume 4.7.1 is not installed? Windows 10 continually upgrades itself. Older versions are *not* supported which means all Windows 10 machines will have 4.7.2 unless an administrator took explicit actions to prevent upgrades. [4.7.2 was added in the Windows 10 April 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10)

Comment: I checked in registry Key path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full. the value for the key Release  is '460805'. this implies it is .Net framework 4.7.0. The OS version is Windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: You asked about **Windows 10**, not Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: Appologies, corrected OS version.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because Microsoft Visual Studio installer considers only first two digits of version.
To overcome from this situation you can create **Launching condition** to prevent installer to be launched if required version of .Net framework is 4.7.1 is not installed even 4.7 is installed on machine.

See **Defining Launching Conditions** section in https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwgwpam_1/1.0.4/en-US/c5/88c211fa174464800b9d457182e4be/content.htm?no_cache=true